# MySQL Error When Copying or Importing Database

Tags: mysql

I have a problem that I cannot find a solution nowhere.

In my project I have database that has tables with multiple FULLTEXT indexes. I tried to export and import, copy database but it gives the error:

```
#1795 - InnoDB presently supports one FULLTEXT index creation at a time
```

What should I do to copy this database? And I wonder that if anything happens to this database, won't be I able to restore it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try a different engine i.e. on which you were able to create those indexes? You have not provided any informations other than the error.

Comment: I created those indexes with InnoDB engine. The only thing I wanted to do is export the database and import another one.

I found a solution by myself. In the .sql file, changed the lines 

ALTER TABLE `videos`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD FULLTEXT KEY `video_baslik` (`video_baslik`), ADD FULLTEXT KEY `video_aciklama` (`video_aciklama`);

to 

ALTER TABLE `videos`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
 ALTER TABLE `videos`
 ADD FULLTEXT KEY `video_baslik` (`video_baslik`);
 ALTER TABLE `videos`
 ADD FULLTEXT KEY `video_aciklama` (`video_aciklama`);

and it worked. But there must be some other way I think

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @ConsiderMe I use MySQL 5.6

Comment: Please get familiar with http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67004

Answer (score 0):

This still seems to be an issue in MySQL 5.6.35.

```
ALTER TABLE `products_description`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`products_id`,`language_id`), ADD KEY `products_name` (`products_name`), ADD KEY `language_id` (`language_id`,`products_keywords`), ADD KEY `language_id_2` (`language_id`,`products_name`), ADD KEY `seo_boost_index` (`gm_url_keywords`,`products_id`,`language_id`), ADD FULLTEXT KEY `products_name_2` (`products_name`);
```

Changed it to...

```
ALTER TABLE `products_description`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`products_id`,`language_id`), ADD KEY `products_name` (`products_name`), ADD KEY `language_id` (`language_id`,`products_keywords`), ADD KEY `language_id_2` (`language_id`,`products_name`), ADD KEY `seo_boost_index` (`gm_url_keywords`,`products_id`,`language_id`);

ALTER TABLE `products_description`
ADD FULLTEXT KEY `products_name_2` (`products_name`);
```

Now the database can be imported without issues.