# MySQL error when copying/importing database

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, innodb

the premise to my problem is this: 
I know very little about MySQL, and I have a MySQL database of a wordpress blog that I'm trying to copy between two instances of XAMPP, from one under OS X, to the other under Windows 7. I assume they both are InnoDB, not sure, though. Both XAMPP versions are the latest to date.

I export the database to an .sql file with all the default settings and then try to import it into an empty database of the same name, when it gets to this table

---

Indexes for table `wp_posts`

```
ALTER TABLE `wp_posts`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`), ADD KEY `post_name` (`post_name`), 
ADD KEY `type_status_date` (`post_type`,`post_status`,`post_date`,`ID`), 
ADD KEY `post_parent` (`post_parent`), ADD KEY `post_author` (`post_author`), 
ADD FULLTEXT KEY `crp_related` (`post_title`,`post_content`), 
ADD FULLTEXT KEY `crp_related_title` (`post_title`), 
ADD FULLTEXT KEY `crp_related_content` (`post_content`);
```

---

I get this error:

> `#1795 - InnoDB presently supports one FULLTEXT index creation at a time`

What should I do to succesfully copy the database over?

I understand it's an InnoDB bug of some kind, Googling the exact error phrase I found this thread
[MySQL Error When Copying or Importing Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26527241/mysql-error-when-copying-or-importing-database)
but I don't know enough to understand what the OP did to his db so it worked...

I also found this
http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/feature-requests/1553/
I understand this is directly related to the error i'm getting, and that it probably tells a solution ("That is why PhpMyAdmin at export should separate creation of FULLTEXT indexes into few SQL commands") but I don't know enough to understand that either, and Googling further about FULLTEXT only finds pages about "fulltext search" function.

But what should I DO, exactly? Please advice.

Comment: This is a bug fixed in 5.6.8 http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67004 Just run a few separate ALTER statements to add the keys needed or upgrade mysql

Comment: maybe add the fulltext index after the table has been created.

Comment: >ALTER statements to add the keys needed<
>maybe add the fulltext index after the table has been created<

could you please elaborate more on how I can do that? 
I am sorry, this probably seems obvious to you both, but I really know *very* little about the workings of mysql.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE wp_posts ADD FULLTEXT KEY crp_related (post_title,post_content)` and so on for each index.Split that statement in multiple parts one for each key.

Comment: do "key" and "index" in this case means the same? So then, is this quite right, how I understand it: I go to phpMyAdmin > SQL on the computer from which I want to export the DB, and "statement" is a command I enter there, in separate lines, using ALTER TABLE [table_name] ADD FULLTEXT KEY [index_name] (index_col_name,...) and then I export the DB and try again until there are no error messages on import with more keys to change? Also, I looked, XAMPP includes MySQL 5.6.20

Comment: Yes they are the same.But if you want to export a dn use mysqldump.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2hsOk0XcYC4

Comment: thank you, I should look for a tutorial on how to use mysqldump under OS X then